# simpleXML returns empty element

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplexml, feed

I got a problem reading an XML-Feed
Sample of the XML File:

```
<f:feed xmlns:f="http://www.bbgo.de/feedxml/feed" xmlns:a="http://www.bbgo.de/feedxml/article" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" f:customer="blub" f:name="dax-tecdax">
<f:title>Analysen: DAX, TecDAX</f:title>
<f:date>2010-09-22T20:46:29+02:00</f:date>
<f:url>http://www.bbgo.de/export/feed/stock-channel/dax-tecdax</f:url>
<f:articles>
<a:article a:id="2310446" a:status="published" a:payed-content="false" xml:lang="de-DE">
<a:title>Kabel Deutschland mit Verkaufsempfehlung</a:title>...
```

A simple test like:

```
$feed = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
print_r($feed);
```

produces

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
```

if i try

```
echo $xml;
```

the above sample is echoed correctly.

Why $feed array is not built? How can I access all `<a:article>` in `<f:articles>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I access all `<a:article>` in `<f:articles>` ?

To me simpleXML seems a bit clumsy when working with namespaces (but then again, I'm not a PHP coder). You could use the `children` method but in my opinion using XPath is simpler.

```
$feed->registerXPathNamespace('f', 'http://www.bbgo.de/feedxml/feed');
$feed->registerXPathNamespace('a', 'http://www.bbgo.de/feedxml/article');
$article = feed->xpath("/f:feed/f:articles/a:article");
```

First you need to register the namespaces with some prefixes (prefixes don't need to match the ones used in the XML document but namespace URIs must match) and then use these prefixes in your XPath expression that selects your target. Without the element name prefixes the XPath expression would look for elements that are not in any namespace.

> Why $feed array is not built?

It's hard to guess a reason for this. Some things you could test:

- is the string `$xml` a well-formed xml document
- does creating a SimpleXMLElement with explicit string parameter work `$feed = new SimpleXMLElement('<root><child/></root>');`
- can you load your document using `simplexml_load_file($yourXMLfile);` or `simplexml_load_string($yourXMLstring);`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and turns out the issue was CDATA related.

So initially I used this:

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file($rss_url);
```

And I got empty description object back like op:

```
[description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
   (
   )
```

But then I found this solution in comments of PHP.net site, saying I needed to use LIBXML_NOCDATA flag: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file($rss_url, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

After making this change, I got description like this:

```
[description] => My description text!
```

Not exactly sure how apply LIBXML_NOCDATA to SimpleXMLElement directly though.